# UIDatePicker storing only time in core data

Tags: xcode, macos, core-data

I am using a `UIDatePicker` with time only.  How can I store this type in the core data, would it be `date:S`?

Comment: How are you storing this exactly? CoreData allows a 'date' type which maps directly to NSDate. This will store a UTC Date/Time value specifically. Are you converting the date to a string or something and storing that? Please post the codes ;)

Comment: Well I havnt stored it yet but I want to know before I do so, so should I convert the selected value to NSDate and then store it...The thing is I want to get these values out as Times and do some calculation e.g show the latest time first.

Comment: You get the date/time from the picker by sending it the date message. That returns an NSDate which you can just store in your NSManagedObject.

Answer (score 0):

You should store it as a date object in Core Data and then you can display it however you want using a `NSDateFormatter`.